# Importar el script1 en el script2 da como resultado un ModuleNotFoundError, aunque el primer script está ahí

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo un proyecto sobre pycharm:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En `views.py` intento importar librerias:

```
import config
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.http import JsonResponse
import pandas as pd

username = config.username
password = config.password
```

Pero me contesta el compilador que:

```
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Projects\todowoo\webapp\scentmate\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from todo import views
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Projects\todowoo\webapp\todo\views.py", line 12, in <module>
    import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

No sé si es vinculado pero viene desde que añadí un archivo (de procesamiento de datos ingeridos).:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tal vez con `from todo import config`?

Comment: Tienes en la carpeta config.py algunas variables con el nombre de username y password con dicha información ?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta importar el módulo así:

```
import .config
```

O como más habitualmente se haría:

```
   from .config import specific_function
```